# Blog app with laravel 5.6 api and vue.js

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2

I have two projects. The first is laravel 5.6 project which contains api for getting posts.
The second project is vue.js project and it will be used toa display all posts. Please help me how to configure vue.js project to get data from laravel api?

Answer (score 0):

Host both projects separately and Rest api will connect two projects. This is only a one way to address your problem.